# Data viz (colour choice) for overlapping elements

Tags: r, colors, data-visualization, visualization

Having issues displaying multiple instances of behaviours (vertical coloured bars) where they overlap or occur at the same times. Been playing around with different ways of visualising it. The two images show my issue, in the first there is no transparency settings and some instances of behaviours are hidden, in the second where transparency is altered it reveals some of these behaviours. Is there a way of making it so all are visible? either through additional code or colour choice? I have multiple graphs like this that I need the same palette to work across so this is just one example.

I've read I shouldnt use lines or shapes, but also read using transparency is frowned upon and instead should just use a lighter colour. There is also the issue of people with colour vision deficiency - has anyone experienced a problem like this and come up with a work-around?

Without transparency:

[image]

With transparency:

[image]

```
gb <- read_csv("p01t01UW.csv") #read in gaze behaviour (horizontal blocks)
mb <- read_csv("p04MBt5.csv") #read in movement (vertical bars)

bhvr <- c(vea = "#ff330010", controllines = "#66ccff70", tack = "#3366ff") # set colour scheme for vertical blocks

mb$Behaviour <- factor(mb$Behaviour, levels = names(bhvr), ordered = TRUE) # retain all behaviour even if not on trial 

ggplot() +
  geom_rect(
    aes(xmin = MBstrt
        , xmax = MBstop
        , fill = Behaviour
        , ymin = 0
        , ymax = 25)
    ,filter(mb, !is.na(Behaviour))

  ) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = c(2:21, 23))
             , col = "gray20"
             , size = 0.25) +
  geom_rect(
    aes(xmin = Fstart
        , xmax = Fstop
        , ymin = AOIcode - 1/3
        , ymax = AOIcode + 1/3)
    , gb
    , fill = "black"
  ) +
  xlab("Time (milliseconds)") +
  ylab("Area of interest") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 25),
                     breaks = c(2:21, 23),
                     labels = c("Bow", "Mast", "Boom & Control lines", "Watch", "Wind indicator", "Sail", "Window", "Tell-tales", "Laser other", "Opponent", "Opponent to stern", "Sea", "Sea 2", "Sea to stern", "Sea to stern 2", "Non-Laser boat", "Other", "Coach's boat", "Pin buoy", "Committee-boat buoy", "No cursor")) +

  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = bhvr, drop=FALSE) +

  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

Should add I'm using Rstudio, with GGplot2, readr, magrittr and dplyr packages

Comment: is the data necessary for a colour question? Start getting into issues with confidentiality. I'll add code to original post now

Comment: Wow, then it's not what you need. You need your code fixed! Crap, I got it wrong again lol. You've done a great job with your code, I stuffed up the answer. I can see what you mean with the transparency, you want to show the underlying differences

Comment: I apologize, and I hope someone else can help.  I have let you down.

Comment: You have been helpful, I looked again at the data and changed the order of it in the csv so vea is plotted on top of the others and I've gone for a light colour for that and brighter for the infrequent but longer duration behaviours. Think it's as good as I'll get

Comment: No worries, I'll leave the answer up, mainly for the book content. Munzer's book is worth reading if you get some time.  Haha, sometimes reordering the data is the best method in solving a problem.  Also don't be afraid to use transparencies, it definitely showed wider and narrower values. Interesting data you get to play with, best of luck :)

Comment: an yeah, my bad, i'm new to this editing stuff.  I delete my answer but then it deleted a comment you made, so I stuck it up top, but then it said that I said it. My appologies.

Answer (score 1):

> Data visualisations 101 - My take on it anyway.

Sorry, I miss read the question, you can take away the code and yes I understand the data is sensitive so I will delete that in a sec.

If your variable "behaviour" is categorical, which, it seems to be, i.e. as a factor, then best practice is to use spatial . o O as first line of attack and then colour.

**Colour** and **Hue** are treated the same for categorical data. "For small regions, designers should use bright, highly saturated colors to ensure that the color coding is distinguishable. When colored regions are large, as in backgrounds, the design guideline is the opposite: use low-saturation colors; that is, pastels." (Munzer, 2014)

So area's of greater volume use low-saturation colours, and bright for small area's.  If they can change depending on the data being captured then make an executive decision and stick to it.  In other words tack should be lighter in colour, yet as it may change then go with what feels right as  people have been making graphs longer than people like Munzer have been picking then to pieces.

Transpency adds a forth level and would be not recommended for what you are doing.  Work on the previous step first.

If the colour represents a numerical values then this is a big fat no, you shouldn't do it, position and scale is used instead, which you have done.

**Colour blind friendly palette** - on a basic level: Red against green are difficult to see or distinguish, yet your graph is all blue, so it will be colour blind friendly.

Notice how in a colour blind friendly palette they do not put green and red in the same palette, exception seems to be last palette in picture but it is mostly blue. See figure below:

[image]

Lastly, if you have 3D paint, paint or something like that in windows, you can pick the colours of your business logo, get there hex code and put them in your design for the categorical variables you want to highligh.  Any trouble with that, then just give me a hoy and I can help you with that.

Cheers

> Reference 
>   Visualization Analysis and Design by Tamara Munzner 2014

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. In this instance I'm unable to use . O as I'm looking to show how gaze (horizontal) relates to certain movements (vertical) over a time period. The reason for using transparency would be that where two instances of behaviour occur at the same time and for the same durations then one always seems to be hidden regardlss of colour chosen. I accept transparency is problematic though as I end up essentially creating a 4th colour. Whilst size of vertical blocks always differs, the frequencies are similar in that VEA is very common, tack and control lines less so

Comment: Wow, then it's not what you need. You need your code fixed! Crap, I got it wrong again lol.  You've done a great job with your code, I stuffed up the answer.  I can see what you mean with the transparency, you want to show the underlying differences.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of any DataViz initiative is to communicate. The best way to determine how successful the viz does that job is to talk to your audience. Do they understand it? Do the colors or other design feature occlude meaning? You might find that you need more or less resolution. Or you might see that there's a more efficient way to reach them.

Specifically, if you want the black elements to stand out more, you will dial back the bar alpha, so they move to the background. However, if you want the user to focus on the bars, then you'll have to try and figure out how to keep the overall visual balanced. You might have to split the visual into two so that a dense display doesn't obscure the meaning.

But again, I highly recommend talking to your audience and see what works best for them.